# independent form submit button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've a form and I've a submit button in it.

What I want is to place the submit button outside the  tag (because of design issues) but still want to be able to submit the form when I click on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a javascript either function or add it directly to the submit button.

```
<input type='button' value='submit' onClick="document.formName.submit()" >
```

-- or --

```
<a href="javascript:document.formName.submit();">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: Because the problem can probably be solved with CSS. Although, this answer did teach me something new...so...*votes up*

Answer (score 5):

if you use jquery,

```
<form name="getform" id="theform" target="/baby/index.html">
...
</form>

<button value="submit" onclick="$('#theform').submit();" />
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to move anything form related out of the form element.
If the form element messes up your design, you should solve this using CSS:

```
form
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I'm racking my brain trying to figure out what design problem could only be fixed by moving the submit button outside of the `form` tags. :P

Comment: Perhaps he has a general submit button as part of a generic UI framework.

Comment: @Bitsplitter I fail see why using a generic UI framework should imply an independent submit button. Sounds like bad design, then...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others answers. This is just one more possibility using `<button>` instead `<input>`. Please take a look on my example.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function myFunction(form_id)
      {
      document.getElementById(form_id).submit();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="id_form" method="post" action="handler.php">
      Username <input type="text" name="Username"></input>
      Password <input type="password" name="Password"></input>
    </form>

    <form id="otherid_form" method="post" action="otherhandler.php">
      Guestname <input type="text" name="Username"></input>
    </form>
    <button onclick="myFunction('id_form')"> submit text</button>
    ...more more stuff if you want...
    <button onclick="myFunction('otherid_form')"> submit text</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With HTML5, you can simply do :

```
<form id="theForm">
...
</form>

<button type="submit" form="theForm">OK</button>
```